# Wrap Column title text, column_spec not working for kable_styling

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have a table that is being printed.  I've specified column width in the `column_spec` function , however the titles of my columns are not wrapping to fit the specified width.

Code looks like this;

```
 kable(ranknew, format = "latex",  row.names = FALSE, 
     align = c("c", "l", "r", "r", "r"), 
     caption = paste("We had", nrow(ranknew) , 
     "brokerages give us 100+ new policies in", year(Sys.Date())-1), 
     longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%  
 kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header"), full_width = F, font_size = 9, position = "center")  %>% 
 column_spec(column = 1, width = "3cm")%>% 
 column_spec(column = 2, width = "8cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 3, width = "2cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 4, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 5, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
 row_spec(row = 0, bold = TRUE, underline = TRUE, background = "orange", 
          color = "black", italic = FALSE, monospace = FALSE, strikeout = FALSE) %>% 
 print(floating = FALSEFALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

This is what my code produces:

[image]

Obviously I'd like the column titles to wrap. The order of the `column_spec` and `row_spec` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add col.names() to the kable() function in the beggining and remove underline=TRUE from the row_spec() function.

```
kable(ranknew, format = "latex",  row.names = FALSE, 
   col.names = c("Provinces","Brokerage Name","Written Pren....","Loss Ratio","New Business( Whatever comes here)"),
     align = c("c", "l", "r", "r", "r"), 
     caption = paste("We had", nrow(ranknew) , 
     "brokerages give us 100+ new policies in", year(Sys.Date())-1), 
     longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%  
 kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header"), full_width = F, font_size = 9, position = "center")  %>% 
 column_spec(column = 1, width = "3cm")%>% 
 column_spec(column = 2, width = "8cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 3, width = "2cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 4, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 5, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
 row_spec(row = 0, bold = TRUE,  background = "orange", 
          color = "black", italic = FALSE, monospace = FALSE, strikeout = FALSE) %>% 
 print(floating = FALSEFALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

This example works on my end with the iris dataset.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

 kable(iris, format = "latex",  row.names = FALSE, 
       col.names = c("Provinces","Brokerage Name","Written Pren....","Loss Ratio","New Business( Whatever comes here)"),
     longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%  
 kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header"), full_width = F, font_size = 9, position = "center")  %>% 
 column_spec(column = 1, width = "3cm")%>% 
 column_spec(column = 2, width = "8cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 3, width = "2cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 4, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
 column_spec(column = 5, width = "1.5cm") %>% 
 row_spec(row = 0, bold = TRUE, underline = TRUE, background = "orange", 
          color = "black", italic = FALSE, monospace = FALSE, strikeout = FALSE) %>% 
 print(floating = FALSEFALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know why R didn't like the underline = T or the absence of col.names in the kable?

Comment: I would guess there's a conflict in the css of the functions.